# Read .m4a Tags on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, tags, m4a

I recently started building an audio tag editor, but now I find a problem that I can't manage to pass through.
My problem is that I don't know how to read tags in .m4a files.

I used this code to read it on mp3 files using a public external library called "Jaudiotagger", and it worked fine.

```
   try {
       File file = new File(TrackPath);
       AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(file);
       Tag tag = f.getTag();

       audioAlbum.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM));
       audioArtist.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST));
    }catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    };
```

But when I tried with an .m4a file just returns blank strings, even using Mp4Tag and Mp4FieldKey instead of Tag and FieldKey.

Does anyone know any other external library which reads these type of audio files or just any workaround for this?

And I don't want to use Android MediaStore because I want the tags to be merged into the file, so I can move the file to another device and keep them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jaudiotagger processes mp4 and m4a **exactly the same way**

You are using the library to read metadata from the file but it seems to me that you are assuming the file already has artist and album metadata in the file, but probably your second file just doesnt have any metadata in it.

Comment: Jaudiotagger does not work for me for m4a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72154696/mediarecorder-produces-jaudiotagger-cannotreadexception